# is it possible to extract the code of a UItableview from iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working with UITableView in an iPhone Application. The look and feel of the tableview that I want requires some modifications in the overall structure of the UITableView , means I want the source code of UITableView which i can modify according to my requirements and then use that as a customised widget in my Application.

```
In short I want to use the system definition of UITableView so that I can modify that.
This is certainly possible for android but I am not sure about iOS.
```

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do with UITableView that is not possible to accomplish with subclassing and delegation?

Comment: There is a term called `Custom` you can easily customize any control by subclassing, re-drawing, drawing.. See this http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/customizing.html. What you are trying to achieve is crazy. If you can't do it normally, you will never be able to do it by reading the compiled version.